# Full page-width tabular overflows into margin when multicols is used

Tags: tables, margins, multicolumn, multicol

I am looking to create a table that always spans the full width of the page. The columns need to be 20% and 80% of the page's width, respectively. They need to be independent of `\arrayrulewidth` and `\tabcolsep`, i.e. their widths need to be calculated dynamically. The first line should be a header row that is created using the `\multicolumn` command. Besides looking nice, this also gives me the "hard-coded" full-page width, as without it the table shrinks to fit its contents.

This code is part of a larger template that contains a custom command that fills the table with key-value pairs through the optional argument. I stripped away the custom command to the following MWE. The `\twocoltablewidth` length is a result of several hours of fiddling around with `\linewidth`, `\textwidth` and other calculations.

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}


\begin{document}

Textwidth: \the\textwidth

Linewidth: \the\linewidth

Helper lines:

\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \newlength{\twocoltablewidth}
  \setlength{\twocoltablewidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{0.20\dimexpr\twocoltablewidth-\tabcolsep\relax}|p{0.80\twocoltablewidth}|} 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\twocoltablewidth}|}{\cellcolor{yellow}{Title}\hfill{ID}}      \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{gray}\textit{\hfill \textit{Linewidth}}        & \the\linewidth        \\
    \cellcolor{gray}\textit{\hfill \textit{Textwidth}}        & \the\textwidth        \\
    \cellcolor{gray}\textit{\hfill \textit{Twocoltablewidth}} & \the\twocoltablewidth \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The table looks like this (`showframe` used for visual aids).

[image: Problem]

When I now add `@{}` around the vertical center line to suppress the margins, the table no longer overflows but does not look very appealing since column one now overflows into column two.

Workaround

```tex
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.20\dimexpr\twocoltablewidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}|@{}p{0.80\twocoltablewidth}|}
```

[image: Workaround]

I have fiddled with omitting the `\twocoltablewidth`, subtracting amounts of `\tabcolsep` and `\arrayrulewidth`, as well as wrapping the entire table in other environments to force it within the page's bounds. I have not found a solution that works for me. What am I doing wrong? I don't have the option to switch to other packages like `tabularx` unfortunately; the only option I have is `longtable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total width of your tabular environment, when using 2 columns,
is `1\linewidth`  plus `4\tabcolsep`, where `\tabcolsep` is the space which is inserted before and after a column (default value: 6pt),  plus `3\arrayrulewidth`  since there are 3 vertical bars.

The title of the tabular, being a single column has an usable width of
`\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth` as you already established.

See the two examples after your code.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}

\newlength{\twocoltablewidth}

\begin{document}
    
Textwidth: \the\textwidth

Linewidth: \the\linewidth

Helper lines:

\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \setlength{\twocoltablewidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.20\dimexpr\twocoltablewidth-\tabcolsep\relax}|p{0.80\twocoltablewidth}|} 
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\twocoltablewidth}|}{\cellcolor{yellow}{Title}\hfill{ID}}      \\
        \hline
        \cellcolor{gray}\textit{\hfill \textit{Linewidth}}        & \the\linewidth        \\
        \cellcolor{gray}\textit{\hfill \textit{Textwidth}}        & \the\textwidth        \\
        \cellcolor{gray}\textit{\hfill \textit{Twocoltablewidth}} & \the\twocoltablewidth \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\bigskip    

\begin{table}[htb]  
    \setlength{\twocoltablewidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr0.3\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}|p{\dimexpr0.70\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}|} 
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\twocoltablewidth}|}{\cellcolor{blue!20}{Title}\hfill{ID}}     \\
        \hline
        \cellcolor{gray}\hfill \textit{Linewidth}           & \the\linewidth        \\
        \cellcolor{gray}\hfill \textit{Textwidth}           & \the\textwidth        \\
        \cellcolor{gray}\hfill \textit{Twocoltablewidth}    & \the\twocoltablewidth \\
        \cellcolor{gray}\hfill \textit{tabcolsep}           & \the\tabcolsep \\
        \cellcolor{gray}\hfill \textit{arrayrulewidth}      & \the\arrayrulewidth \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\bigskip

\begin{table}[htb]  
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{3pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
    
\setlength{\twocoltablewidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}|p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}|} 
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\twocoltablewidth}|}{\cellcolor{green!10}{Title}\hfill{ID}}     \\
        \hline
        \cellcolor{gray}\hfill \textit{Linewidth}        & \the\linewidth        \\
        \cellcolor{gray}\hfill \textit{Textwidth}        & \the\textwidth        \\
        \cellcolor{gray}\hfill \textit{Twocoltablewidth} & \the\twocoltablewidth \\
        \cellcolor{gray}\hfill \textit{tabcolsep}        & \the\tabcolsep \\
        \cellcolor{gray}\hfill \textit{arrayrulewidth}   & \the\arrayrulewidth \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```